# DotNetNuke Installation 404 error occur

Tags: iis, installation, dotnetnuke

I want to install dotnetnuke on my pc
Informaton are given below.

> 1. Os: Windows 7
> 2. IIS version: 7.5
> 3. DoNet Framework: 4.0
> 4. Sql Server 2008 R2 Express Edition

I follow dotnetnuke video tutorial link and follow all steps mention on this video.
but at the last step when I enter this link www.dnndev.me(Hostname) on the browser.
It show me 100% process of installation and after that when i click on "Visit Website" button 
an error occured:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I don't understand where I make mistake.
Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the following way:

1. Edit web.config (c:\websites\dnndev.me)
2. Searh "friendlyUrl"
3. Change urlFormat="advanced" to urlFormat="humanfriendly"

Answer (score 0):

Check in IIS to make sure you have both WWW.DNNDEV.ME and DNNDEV.ME as Host Bindings.

Also if you go to the URL, try putting default.aspx on the end and see if that loads up or not.